# Counting how many different connection are opened by one ip (per seconds)

Tags: regex, shell, network-programming

I have a network dump (PCAP file) from a "conversation" between a web server apache (192.168.1.2) and some clients:

[image: PCAP file]

This was a simulation of slowloris attack in Apache web server.

Counting how many different connection are opened by one ip:

```
/usr/sbin/tcpdump -anr myfile.pcap |
    sed 's/^.*IP \([^:]*\)192.168.1.2.80:.*/\1/p;d' |
    sort |
    uniq -c
```

This will show a lot of

```
10 192.168.1.8.36684 >
4 192.168.1.8.39619 >
9 192.168.1.8.39856 >
4 192.168.1.8.39896 >
5 192.168.1.8.40195 >
12 192.168.1.8.40196 >
9 192.168.1.8.52288 >
7 192.168.1.8.58529 >
9 192.168.1.8.58639 >
9 192.168.1.8.58730 >
6 192.168.1.8.58835 >
13 192.168.1.8.58851 >
12 192.168.1.8.58852 >
10 192.168.1.8.58882 >
```

I would like to know how to count the number of opened connection per seconds in the PCAP file.

Is this correct?

```
tcpdump -anr slowloris.pcap host 192.168.1.2 and port 80 |
    sed -une '
      s/^\(.\{8\}\).* IP \(.*\)\.[0-9]\+ > 1192.168.1.2.80: Flags \[S\],.*/\1 \2/p
    ' |
    sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: SO is not a coding service. You have to write your code and ask specific questions about it. However, here's a hint: If you want to solve your problem in Python, read the file as a Pandas DataFrame, resample the time to 1-second intervals, and group the results by time and IP address.

Comment: @DYZ: there is a possible answer in my question. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('saida.txt') as f: linhas = f.readlines()

soma = 0 for linha in linhas: soma += int(linha.strip().split(" ")[0])

print(soma)
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!